# Jython and Jackson

Tags: java, python, json, jackson, jython

Firstly, I'm new to Jython. I'm looking for a way to integrate python code into a Java project. Hence I am investigating Jython.

I'm trying to convert a json string to java objects - in python.

Firstly, I've been battling with getting Jython to even find my java classes. In lack of a more elegant solution, I was able to move forward by simply doing the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/anton/workspaces/m/TradePerformance/lib/jackson-databind-2.5.1.jar')
sys.path.append('/home/anton/workspaces/m/TradePerformance/lib/jackson-core-2.5.0.jar')
```

Anyways...

I'm trying the following:

```
url = 'myRestService...'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
print response
import sys

mapper =  ObjectMapper
trades = ArrayList<TradeOrder>()
#trades = mapper.readValue(response, ArrayList<TradeOrder>().__class__, "");
#trades = mapper.convertValue(ArrayList<TradeOrder>().__class__, response)
#trades= mapper.reader
trades = mapper.readValue(response, ArrayList<TradeOrder>().__class__)
```

However, when running I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anton/workspaces/m/TradePerformance/src/com/test/test.py", line 41, in <module>
    trades = mapper.readValue(response, ArrayList<TradeOrder>().__class__);
TypeError: readValue(): expected 3-5 args; got 2
```

I'm not sure why Jython is saying it expects 3-5 args. 
According to the JavaDocs on http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html
 this method has 3 overloads, and all expect 2 args.

Anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

`self` counts as an argument.  So, you are actually *are* attempting to pass three arguments.  That's not your problem.

You should leave the `<TradeOrder>` type parameter off of your `ArrayList`s.  It is unnecessary, and actually wrong in Jython.

Comment: Hi David, thanks. I removed `<TradeOrder>`. I didnt undertand what you mean when you say "`self` counts as an argument. I'm not using `self` anywhere.

Comment: When you make a method call, the object that owns the method (on the left-hand side of the dot) is itself passed as an argument to the method.  By convention, Python calls this reference to the method-owning object `self`.  Java and C++ call it `this`.

Comment: Worth noting the following surprising aspect of using Java generic syntax in Python, regardless if CPython or Jython: `A<B>()` is certainly legal, assuming the names `A` and `B` are defined. This is the same as stating `A < B > ()`, and rich comparisons in Python 2 guarantee that all elements in this comparison are comparable; unfortunately no guarantees that `A < B` is `True` or `False` for classes. `True > ()` is `True` (you are comparing against an empty tuple); `False > ()` is `False`. And in the end you're confused! Python 3 fixes: it raises `TypeError: unorderable types: type() < type()`

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your main problem, but as a general best practice with JSON, the root value should always be a JSON Object, and not a scalar or Array. This avoids many, many problems with things like Java type erasure.
This is not to say that you can not make `List`s and such collections work, but that there is extra care needed with generic typing -- work that is unnecessary as long as the root value is an Object.